# How to best handle many accept cases

Tags: java, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

For class I'm working on an interpreter, currently working on the scanner. Being a class that will be called many many times, I would like for it to be optimized for speed. In the scanner, to categorize an operator you have to compare the current token to the 6 or so operators. What method is best for speed, but for also for readability.

1. Many cases in an if statement
2. Loop through a char array of every operator and compare
3. Switch statement

These are the only cases I could think of. Which is best, or if you have a better approach please share. I implemented #2 because it takes up the least amount of lines of code.

Comment: Don't bother with "speed" until you can demonstrate that it's a problem.  You are going down the premature optimization rabbit hole. If I were you I'd use regex alternation or character class.

Comment: Switch statements are the most readable when working with single character lexers, and they incur a relatively low overhead IIRC. Just stick with that.

Comment: I doubt you will see any speed difference with only 6 operators.

Comment: Guys, it's not just the 6 operators. There are several dozen start states, including A..Z, a..z, 0..9, etc. A `switch` is the only sane way to handle it. There are really only two ways to hand-write scanners, and both of them use `switch`. There isn't much point in learning a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks, I was posting from my phone so I didn't go into that much detail but you understand. That's what I had thought, but where I got confused was what to do with tokens that are longer than one character. From your answer, I see that you get your token inside the switch rather than before. I'm going to try to refactor mine into something like that for fun.

Comment: @shmallow I'm surprised you weren't already shown how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sensible hand-written scanner is based on a switch statement. Note that if you return special characters directly to the parser as themselves, you can economize on case actions:

```
switch (ch) // the next incoming character
{
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '%':
    // etc.
        return ch;
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    // ...
    case 'Z':
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    // ...
    case 'z':
        // start of an identifier: accumulate it, with a do/while loop,
        // save it somewhere, return IDENTIFIER
        return IDENTIFIER;
    case '0':
    case '1':
    // ...
    case '9':
        // start of a numeric literal: ...
        return NUMERIC_LITERAL;
    // etc. 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For just a few items, the difference is small. If you have many items you should definitely use a switch.

If a switch contains more than five items, it's implemented using a lookup table or a hash list. This means that all items get the same access time, compared to a list of `if` where the last item takes much more time to reach as it has to evaluate every previous condition first.

And also as @Qix commented `switch` it more readable.

Comment: This is urban myth. The Sun/Oracle Java compiler uses the `lookupswitch` opcode even if there is only one `case`.